# Creating custom command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is that possible to create custom commands?Such as when a player type /hi he will get a message "hello!"

I have search on google but the only result i got is using trigger command.

Answer (score 0):

Not in "vanilla" Minecraft. Many mod platforms allow you to create custom commands including:

- [Spigot/Bukkit](https://www.spigotmc.org/)
- [Forge Mod Loader](http://files.minecraftforge.net/)